# Chrome and Mozilla count margin differently

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin, mozilla

I set % margin top in an element and Moz & Chr count it differently. Here is my code:

```
#hohloma {
display:flex;
width:90%;
max-width: 537px; 
margin-top: 10%;
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(../img/hohloma.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin-left:4%;
    position:relative;
```

And how see that Mozilla:
[image]

And how see that Mr. Chrome: 
[image]

Comment: is this div a child of body or another parent? does both browsers have the same viewport dimensions? does the parent have a fixed width?

Comment: this div is not child of body and a parent to other div.  dimensions the same.

Comment: im very sorry i was wrong. it is in body...

Comment: please check if body width is identical

Comment: it is. but i solved the problem. i refused % and set px...

Comment: that's the way to go imo, browser have different borders and default margins so it's a pain to calculate for all of that

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that the containing element have a fixed width and is the same in both browsers.

> % - specifies a margin in % of the width of the containing element

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Comment: width is fixed.